ABAP insert internal table with dynamic name
In ABAP we can insert value into internal table with:
   insert wa into table my_table.

Question is, if the name of my_table can only be determined at runtime, how to tackle it? Something like following doesn't work unfortunately:
   insert wa into table ('my_table').

I tried with dynamic name in bracket but no success.

Use ASSIGN ('dobj_name') TO <fs_name>:
FIELD-SYMBOLS <any_table> TYPE ANY TABLE.
ASSIGN ('my_table') TO <any_table>.

Minimal reproducible program:
DATA my_table TYPE TABLE OF i.
DATA wa TYPE i.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <any_table> TYPE ANY TABLE.
ASSIGN ('my_table') TO <any_table>.
INSERT wa INTO TABLE <any_table>. " inserts one line in MY_TABLE

Other writing:
FIELD-SYMBOLS <any_table> TYPE ANY TABLE.
DATA(itab_name) = 'my_table'.
ASSIGN (itab_name) TO <any_table>.

Link to the ABAP documentation: ASSIGN, dynamic_dobj

Further information for consideration: it's possible to SORT such a table dynamically:
sort <my_table> by ('comp1') ('comp2') ... ('comp9').

or
sort <my_table> by (comp_table).

At the same time, constructor expressions will be quite limited: it's not possible to use # in the type specification or use dynamic tables in the FILTER and other expressions which require design type information about components.
